# Safety of Generalized Override of Object.equals() Method With Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, overriding

I'm tired of having to override Object.equals for all of my classes, so I came up with this overriding method that, if used in all classes in a project, appears would produce desired results.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object anObject){
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    //same class?
    if (anObject.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getFields();
        boolean fieldsEqual = true;
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                fieldsEqual &=
                        field.get(anObject).equals(field.get(this));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { }
        }
        //if fields equal, objects are equal.
        return fieldsEqual;
    }
    //not the same class, so the objects aren't equal
    return false;
}
```

Is this safe? The unhandled `IllegalAccessException` worries me a little, but given that the method first checks if `this` and `anObject` are the same class, I don't think that this would ever happen unless a field was dynamically removed or added from the class during runtime. It looks like this could be a really handy snippet of code if it's safe save for that one exception.

What do the pros here at StackOverflow think?

Comment: Do you need to do it this way? It would be safer and quicker to just compare each value. Otherwise, as long as both objects have all the same fields (which they inherently do after your `getClass()` comparison), I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: Looks like you've reinvented Apache's EqualsBuilder, but reflection has significant runtime cost...

Comment: You know since Java 7 there's Objects.equals, which would reduce significantly the amount of code. Please don't be lazy and don't use reflection for this. IMO this is NOT a good solution. Furthermore, most IDEs can generate them for you.

Comment: Using Reflection for no good reason is a bad idea. Assuming that all fields are public is a bad idea. Accessing any unknown object's properties or methods before checking for `null` is even worse idea.

Comment: I can't think of a single case where I'd check equality by comparing *all* fields on an object. Plus, the hashcode method has to be compatible with this, but if the fields array isn't explicitly sorted in both equals and hashcode then this will not be the case. Then, you'll get illegal access thrown whenever you access a private field -- all my fields are private. Then, what happens with derived fields that only exist via a getter? Not to mention the performance hit.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, Germann. So then I'd call setAccessible and check if null first. There's runtime overhead, sure, but if something needs to be out yesterday (often reality) it looks like it's usable with implementation able to be updated later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a **very bad idea**.

Please either let the IDE generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` for you, or use a library, i.e. Apache Commons Lang [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html), as @Louis Wasserman suggested.

Apart from poor performance and `NullPointerException` being thrown when a field is `null` (as already stated in the comments), your code might run into an infinite loop:

```
public static class Test {

    static class ClassWithUnsafeEqualsMethod {
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object anObject){
            if (this == anObject) {
                return true;
            }
            //same class?
            if (anObject.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
                Field[] fields = this.getClass().getFields();
                boolean fieldsEqual = true;
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    try {
                        fieldsEqual &=
                                field.get(anObject).equals(field.get(this));
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { }
                }
                //if fields equal, objects are equal.
                return fieldsEqual;
            }
            //not the same class, so the objects aren't equal
            return false;
        }
    }

    static class A extends ClassWithUnsafeEqualsMethod {
        B fieldB;
    }

    static class B extends ClassWithUnsafeEqualsMethod {
        A fieldA;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = new A();
        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();

        a1.fieldB = b2;
        b2.fieldA = a1;

        a2.fieldB = b1;
        b1.fieldA = a2;

        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));
    }
}
```

And there you have a nice `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Try it!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that try/catch swallowing the IllegalAccessException is a good idea, that might lead you to a very hairy bug to debug, I would log somewhere.

I usually use the [ApacheCommons equals method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) for equals().